# Getting Access to the touch event in an UIAlertView

Tags: iphone

I am displaying a Customized UIAlertView. I need to know how to get access to the touch events taking place in that AlertView.

I have a controller class which is set as the delegate of my customized UIAlertView, with the following method, but this is not triggered on touching being taking place in AlertView.

```
- (void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
```

Comment: Sorry, I got the answer, touchesBegan need to added to UIView class and not the controller class. Wanted to delete this question but it seems I cant.

Comment: So answer your own question to help others with similar questions

Answer (score 0):

Another solution (instead of overriding UIView and `- (void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event`) could be the usage of UIGestureRecognizer.

[UIGestureRecognizers](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/EventHandling/Conceptual/EventHandlingiPhoneOS/GestureRecognizer_basics/GestureRecognizer_basics.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009541-CH2-SW1) are very powerful and worth a look anyway.

In this case you don't have to deal with inheritance, but can add it to any view.

```
- (id)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame {
    if ((self = [super initWithFrame:frame])) {
        tapRecognizer = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self 
                                                                action:@selector(tapGestureDetected:)];
        [self addGestureRecognizer:tapRecognizer];
    }
    return self;
}

- (void) tapGestureDetected:(UITapGestureRecognizer*)recognizer {   
    int numberOfTapAreas = [self.delegate numberOfTabAreas];
    CGPoint p= [tapRecognizer locationInView:recognizer.view];
    //...
}
```